# Should I be using std::array for very large arrays? What is the idiomatic alternative?

Tags: c++, arrays, stl

I'm doing a college assignment with C++. I mostly have been instructed in C, so I'm putting in some effort to practice more "idiomatic" C++.

In C, I had no issues working with a large dynamically allocated array:

```
int* board = (int*) malloc(2048 * 2048 * sizeof(int));
```

In C++, as I understood, `malloc` shouldn't be used, nor `new` and `delete`, and instead RAII is king. Instead of worrying about allocation and freeing of memory myself, I should prefer to use the STL.

However, this code does not run (but does compile):

```
std::array<int, 2048 * 2048> board;
```

With Valgrind, I noticed that the amount of memory attempted to be allocated on the stack (around 8.4 million `int`s) goes way beyond what the OS is willing to do.

What would be the C++ way to work with large arrays?

Comment: Have you learned about `std::vector` yet?

Comment: This is not a cast you see that often: `int* board = (int*) malloc(2048 * 2048 * sizeof(int));` - I mean, why? Hope the removal of RAII isn't a problem. It has nothing  to what you're asking about.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I have read about it, but from what I understood, `std::vector` is for resizable arrays, no? Since I know the array size in compile time, shouldn't `std::array` be preferred?

Comment: @Magmagan Compiletime arrays are probably a hardware thing. Why are you asking?

Comment: In this case no. Your array won't fit on the stack, so you have to go with either a [static variable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration#Storage_duration) (lives until the program ends and effectively unlimited in size) or a dynamic allocation. As you've correctly recognized RAII is king. Well, `vector`'s pretty much the king of RAII containers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, coming from C:

- `int foo[10]` -> `std::array<int, 10> foo`
- `int* foo = malloc(10 * sizeof(int))` -> `std::vector<int> foo(10)`

`std::array` directly contains all of its elements, just like a C array.  In fact, it's essentially just simple structure like this:

```
template <typename T, size_t N>
struct array
{
    T __unspecified_name[N];

    // Some member functions
};
```

On the other hand, `std::vector` dynamically allocates storage for its elements, just like you would manually do with `malloc`; it just automatically manages re-allocating more storage when needed and frees its allocated storage in its destructor.

---

Another alternative to `malloc` is a smart-pointer like `std::unique_ptr<int[]> foo = std::make_unique<int[]>(10)`.  This can be useful in some specific circumstances (i.e. when memory or code size is extremely tight, or you specifically want the move-only semantics).  This is straying a bit into opinion, but IMO you should generally prefer `std::vector` if you don't have a specific reason to use something else.

Comment: `int* foo = malloc(10 * sizeof(int))` could also be described as `std::unique_ptr<std::array<int, 10>>` depending on the exact use case, but yes, `vector` is the more common approach (and more flexible).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Technically, `malloc(10 * sizeof((int))` would be more closely equated to `std::unique_ptr<int[]>` constructed with `std::make_unique<int[]>(10)`. `std::unique_ptr<std::array<int, 10>>` is always a compile-time size and is encoded in the type, whereas `std::make_unique<T[]>(N)` creates a dynamic size that can be specified as a runtime value and homogeneously stores as a `std::unique_ptr<int[]>`